# How do I connect the wires inside a conduit junction box?

Tags: electrical, conduit

I have some wiring in my garage (done by a sparky believe it or not...) where the wire is quite loose, just tacked to the wall with clips, and there are a few junction boxes as well as the usual switches etc.

I'd like to enclose the wiring in plastic conduit to make it neater and more protected, but I can't for the life of me see how the junctions would work!  All the conduit junction boxes are just empty boxes, e.g. [this one from Screwfix](http://www.screwfix.com/p/tower-3-way-tee-box-20mm-black-pack-of-1/82706)

[image]

Am I supposed to put a "normal" junction box inside of that?  Or do conduit junction boxes exist somewhere that already have wiring blocks in?

Seems a stupid question but I can't found the answer anywhere!

Comment: With electrical questions, it's very useful to include your location because of the variance in codes from country to country (and because the majority of people active on this site are in the US).  I'm guessing you're in the UK from the link to the Screwfix website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You piqued my interest and I have a screwdriver.

Here's how a professional electrician in the UK made joins in wiring in my office building constructed 2001 (so as per regulations at that date).

Not all junctions contain joins. Some do.

[image]
[image]

So yes, use terminal strips (blocks) like [these](http://www.screwfix.com/c/electrical-lighting/terminal-strips/cat830486) - all DIY stores have them, some ironmongers and larger supermarkets too. Make sure they are rated for the current they'll carry.

As you know, Part P of current UK building [regulations](http://www.planningportal.gov.uk/permission/commonprojects/electrics) apply to DIY work on wiring connected to mains supply.

Comment: Cool thanks, that's exactly what I'm going to do.  I've also found out since, that conduit is generally wired with single core cable, rather than the usual twin+earth, which explains some of my confusion.  

My understanding is that it's only when Part P becomes notifiable that DIYers can't really do it.

Comment: DO NOT TURN OFF? It looks off.  I mean, IT LOOKS OFF,

Answer (score 0):

The connections are made in the plastic boxes with wire nuts, just like in a regular metal box.  I'm not really sure what you are referring to as wiring blocks. Blocks or terminal strips are not normally used in a simple j-box.

Comment: I'm trying to replace this - http://www.screwfix.com/p/30a-3-terminal-heavy-duty-junction-box/73522 with something I can attach conduit to to protect the cabling.  But that junction box has screw terminals (what I called "wiring blocks" above) to join wires to, whereas conduit boxes don't seem to.  I can't find what I need to use or how to do it!

Comment: Ok, first of all, you must be in Europe, not the US.  My take on this may not be applicable in your area.  I really have no idea what products and methods are common there.  Sorry.

Comment: This global DIY keeps falling apart on electrical, doesn't it?

Comment: I have seen short terminal strips used in place of wire nuts in European wiring while visiting there. (Wasn't the UK though, and I reside in the US) They were shoved into the box with no other fastening besides the wire just as wire nuts would be. OP could perhaps enquire at a large home improvement store from someone that seems knowledgeable as to what the local common wiring methods are. (I know, no one is knowledgeable at such places, but once in a while you get lucky)

Comment: I'm no expert but I'd use a [terminal strip](http://www.screwfix.com/c/electrical-lighting/terminal-strips/cat830486) of the appropriate rating for the wire gauge and matching/exceeding the rating of the circuit breaker supplying that section of wiring from the house. I've not seen a "wire nut" sold or used in the UK (but my experience is limited).

Comment: @philip: Seems we are a bit weak on European electrical issues.